# How can I create a constructor in a Yii2 model

Tags: constructor, model, yii2

How can I create a constructor in a Yii2 model? because i want to convert a CI model to Yii2 model.

I would appreciate a working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create this function in your model class:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

From the official documentation:

> It is recommended that you perform object initialization in the init() method because at that stage, the object configuration is already applied.
>   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-baseobject.html

So it depends a bit on what exactly you want to do in your constructor. For most cases, this would be the standard approach:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    // ... initialization after configuration is applied
}
```

Comment: Note that [the official docs for Model](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#__construct()-detail) explicitly tell you to *"call the parent implementation at the end of the constructor."*.  The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58763932/286685) by [TomoMiha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557432/tomomiha) shows an example that follows the official recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#__construct()-detail) tells us:

> If this method is overridden in a child class, it is recommended that
>
> - the last parameter of the constructor is a configuration array, like `$config` here.
> - call the parent implementation at the end of the constructor.

So create a standard constructor in your model, but
call parent::__construct() in the last line:

```
public function __construct($config = []) {
     // your init code here
     // ...
     parent::__construct($config);
}

// Controller

$model = new YourModel(['whatever' => []])
```